# Issue at programming the power supply via RS232 interface

Tags: power-supply, serial, rs232

I’m trying to program DC power supply which I recently bought via RS232 interface. When I try to send commands, I always get '0' value as a return no matter which command I sent. I’m hoping someone to point my mistake.

Device: UNI-T UTP3305C

COM Settings;

```
           Baudrate: 9600
           Parity: None
           Data Bit: 8
           Stop Bit: 1
```

[image]

Datasheet: https://www.uni-trend.com/uploadfile/cloud/English%20manual/Benchtop%20Instrument/UTP3000C%20English%20manual.pdf

Comment: Check your cable whether it's the same pinout as the datasheet, some cable are crossed. Also make sure you have the GND connected on pin 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a rebranded Korad.

The firmware is a bit buggy and there's a very short timeout, so if you enter commands manually it won't work, it will timeout before you've finished typing the command. You have to send the whole command at once.

Try this Python3 code.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import serial, time, sys, re

class KoradException( Exception ):
    pass

class KD3005P( object ):
    def __init__( self, serial_port, debug=False ):
        # Open serial port. Note: RTS CTS does not seem to work
        self._ser = serial.Serial( serial_port, baudrate=9600, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, timeout=0.1,
            rtscts=True, write_timeout=0.5 )
        self.serial_port = serial_port
        self._debug      = debug
        self._wait_until = 0.

        self.id = ""
        self.set_name( "" )

        self.retries = 1
        self.id = self.get_idn()
        self.retries = 4
        self.set_name( "" )
        print("Initialized", self.name)

    def set_name( self, name ):
        self.name = name + " " + self.id + " " + self.serial_port


    # serial transaction, string or bytes input, bytes output
    def _tx( self, command, recv_bytes ):
        # serial.write() wants bytes, not str
        if not isinstance( command, bytes ):
            command = command.encode("ascii")
        self._ser.flushInput()
        self._ser.write( command )
        response = self._ser.read( recv_bytes )
        if( isinstance( response, bytes )):
            response = response.decode("ascii")
        if len(response) != recv_bytes :
            msg = "%s: %s Response %r is %d bytes, expected %d bytes\n" % (self.name, command, response, len(response), recv_bytes)
            sys.stderr.write( msg )
            raise KoradException( msg )
        if self._debug:
            print( "%s: %s %r" % (self.name, command, response) )
        return response



    def _com( self, command, recv_bytes=0 ):
        # serial.write() wants bytes, not str
        if not isinstance( command, bytes ):
            command = command.encode("ascii")

        #   This power supply uses RCP - Retarded Communication Protocol.
        #
        #   Some commands make the micro busy for a while during which it does not listen to new commands.
        #   Since there are no ACKlownedge messages, if a command is not supposed to return any response,
        #   it is impossible to know if it was executed or not.
        #
        #   However, if the command we're about to send is supposed to return a known length response
        #   that can be validated, then if we get a valid response, we know the micro was ready!
        #   These commands are IOUT? VOUT? ISET? VSET? ; it is easy to check if the return is a valid float.
        #   Status and others that return just a byte cannot be validated, the byte could be leftover garbage.
        #
        first_command = "IOUT1?"
        if command in ("IOUT1?", "ISET1?", "VOUT1?", "VSET1?"):
            first_command = command

        for retry in range( self.retries ):
            try:                    response = self._tx( first_command, 5 )
            except KoradException:  continue

            # validate response
            if first_command[:1]=="V" and re.match( r"^\d\d\.\d\d$", response ): break
            if first_command[:1]=="I" and re.match( r"^\d\.\d\d\d$", response ): break

            sys.stderr.write( "%s: -1- %s Response %r is not a float\n" % (self.name, first_command, response) )
            time.sleep(0.2)
        else:
            raise KoradException( "%s: -1- %s too many retries, giving up\n" % (self.name, first_command) )

        # If the test command was actually the command we wanted to do, then it's done.
        # return the float result. If we used IOUT1, we got the result for free, maybe do something with it?
        if first_command == "IOUT1?":  self.last_iout1 =float(response)
        if first_command == command:    return response

        # now execute the command we came here for originally.
        for retry in range( 4 ):
            try:                    return self._tx( command, recv_bytes )
            except KoradException:  time.sleep(0.2)
        else:
            raise KoradException( "%s: -2- %s too many retries, giving up\n" % (self.name, first_command) )

    def on( self ):
        self._com('OUT1')

    def off( self ):
        self._com('OUT0')

    def get_idn( self ):
        return self._com('*IDN?',30)

    # Is it in constant current mode?
    def get_cc( self ):
        return not (1 & self._com( "STATUS?", 1 )[0] )

    # Returns set() of "ON"/"OFF" and "CC"/"CV"
    def get_status( self ):
        r = self._com( "STATUS?", 1 )[0]
        s = set()
        if r & 1:   s.add("CV")
        else:       s.add("CC")
        if r & 64:  s.add("ON")
        else:       s.add("OFF")
        return s

    def get_current_setpoint( self ):
        return float( self._com('ISET1?',5) )

    def get_voltage_setpoint( self ):
        return float( self._com('VSET1?',5) )

    def get_current( self ):
        return float( self._com('IOUT1?',5) )

    def get_voltage( self ):
        return float( self._com('VOUT1?',5) )

    def _set( self, command, value, validate=True ):
        for retry in range( 4 ):
            self._com( command+":"+value )
            if not validate:
                return
            readback = self._com( command+'?',5)
            if readback == value:
                return
            print( self.name, "Retry", command, "got:", readback )
        raise KoradException( "%s: -2- %s:%s too many retries, giving up\n" % (self.name, command, value) )

    def set_current( self, value, validate=True ):
        value = "%05.03f" % min( max(value,0), 5.095 )
        self._set( 'ISET1', value, validate )

    def set_voltage( self, value, validate=False ):
        value = "%05.02f" % min( max(value,0), 30 )
        self._set( 'VSET1', value, validate )

    def set_ocp( self, value ):
        if value:   self._com( 'OCP1' )
        else:       self._com( 'OCP0' )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried it but get an error:                                                                                                                                
COM9: b'IOUT1?' Response '' is 0 bytes, expected 5 bytes
pwr = KD3005P('COM9') ...
... raise KoradException( "%s: -1- %s too many retries, giving up\n" % (self.name, first_command) )
__main__.KoradException:   COM9: -1- IOUT1? too many retries, giving up

Comment: Test your serial cable by connecting RX and TX, see if you get echo by typing stuff in the terminal. If that works, then connect to power supply and try the set voltage or set current command, the power supply should display the voltage change on the front panel. If that works then you probably have a connection problem on serial RX.

Comment: Thanks a lot , after the testing we found out that usb to rs232 converter was faulty.

Comment: Nice! I hope you find the code useful.

Comment: Actually i'm getting error from the code, this time write timeout. response;             
                                                                                                                                     ...self._tx( first_command, 5 ) ...                                                       
                                                                                
...serial.serialutil.SerialTimeoutException: Write timeout

Comment: Probably rts/cts problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39032581/python-serial-write-timeout

Comment: This solved the write error problem... Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @U.Sim There's so many USB to RS232 converters out there that are utter crap. My advise is to stick to some well-known brand like FTDI, it will save you many hours of troubleshooting.

Comment: 2 weeks ago I had huge headache with USB RS232 that flipped random bits

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the advice. Device i used was Digitus brand which have FTDI chipset. Actually my trust to the device was what made me reluctant to test it.